# How to deal with meta-duplicates (disparate problems with the same root cause)?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

By *meta-duplicates* for the lack of better term I mean seemingly different questions (sometimes from completely different domains) which discuss issues with the same root cause and therefore could be answered with the same canonical answer.

For example I have seen literally hundreds and hundreds of questions seemingly about different issues with different shell commands complaining about wrong parameters (or anything else for that matter) which are actually caused by just improper use of quoting and/or special symbol escaping. One popular use case is a development for Android where one develops on a computer and then deploys the build artifacts to a mobile device for testing. Frequently both deployment and testing require running some Android shell commands.

Usually people are just trying to follow somebody else's instructions and they do not have a deep understanding of what's going on. They just copy-n-paste some command from the guide verbatim but it does not work. Then they come to SE and post another *The COMMAND does not work!!!* question.

And the actual reason for the failure was that the *command* was meant to be run in the Android shell directly and the asker was trying to run it from their host PC instead by prepending the command with `adb shell`. What they failed to realize was that the command was now parsed twice and depending on the host PC OS (and/or version of the shell/command interpreter) some symbols deemed special by the outer (i.e. host computer) shell had been already altered (removed/substituted/etc) before they got to the inner Android shell for processing. A slight variation of that scenario would be the case where the *original command* was already prepared for shell nesting but it was meant for a different outer shell.

AFAIK the proper canonical answer does not exist for this specific issue. And I might be inclined to write one up. But I get the feeling that closing of questions as duplicates of it would be almost universally rejected by the majority of people who come to SE looking for copy-n-paste recipes for their specific problem and are not particularly interested in finding the root cause and having to do a tiny bit of research of their own in order to apply the generic solution to their specific case. And frequently even close vote reviewers do not bother to understand the common root cause and reject the flag.

So, what should be the proper way of handling such questions?

Comment: If there is a Q&A with an answer which also answers another question, then close it. Just because OP is too lazy to read and understand that duplicate doesn't make it a duplicate question. There are already plenty of "canonical Q&As" out there and used for closing questions.

Comment: @Emna, the question you linked is about absolutely different issue. not even close.

Comment: sorry ! for that it's just a possible way not sure

Comment: @Tom, I understand all that. But I would still like to see if the majority of reviewers would agree with me on what the duplicate question really means. Thus my question.

Comment: Well, this depends on the reviewers, but, yes, they should. This might help: [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992)

Comment: Are you saying for the problem you describe an approach similar as shown in [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) doesn't work?

Comment: @rene, *NullReference Exception* is almost the opposite type of the issue that I am talking about. There you get similarly sounding error message for the whole range of issues covered in the canonical answer. I was talking more about those questions where OP (and most reviewers) actively reject the idea of the question being duplicate based  on the fact that they were trying to use a different command or got a different error message.

Comment: for a moment there, I thought you were speaking about meta-*meta*-duplicates, that is, questions that have been asked over and over again on meta...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing two things:

- Questions that happen to have the same answer, and
- Questions that describe different issues, but all have the same underlying reason.

The later is the situation you use example of: people don't run commands where they should. Those are, down to earth, duplicates. It will be a challenge to write a canonical Q&A that solves all those issues (maybe something like "Where should I run these commands?"), but it should be possible.

Now, for illustrating the former, I will use my favorite example, Virtualbox. The guest system in a virtualized environment like VB, has some limitations: lack of USB3 support, can't share directories with the host, doesn't have direct access to hardware acceleration, long etc. Well, all of those are solved by installing virtualbox guest additions. It has some or other appendage, but the answer boils down to that. But that doesn't mean that they are duplicates! The most obvious reason is that if Oracle decides tomorrow to separate the guest additions in several packages, then installing the package corresponding to the specific question will be necessary.

So, while I agree that we should strive to create a general question that deals with the example you use, we should be very careful of using the same metric for other cases.

Comment: Mind throwing this example onto [my MSE question asking for valid same-answer non-duplicates](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267318/are-there-any-non-trivial-examples-of-exact-duplicate-answers-to-non-duplicate-q)?

Comment: @NathanTuggy the virtualbox one?

Comment: Yeah, that one.