# What (if any) action should be taken when the same answer appears on several questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Going through the review queue for the late answers I've spotted that the same answer is literally copy-pasted to several questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810012/5366641

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51809974/5366641

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51809943/5366641

I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270841/what-to-do-with-same-answers-from-one-user-on-multiple-questions), but the accepted answer there gives general guidelines. Here I am speaking about a specific case. So what to do in this particular case?

Comment: Note the first one has already been dealt with by Yvette with the message "Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Instead, tailor the answer to the question asked. If the questions are exact duplicates of each other, please vote/flag to close instead".

Comment: Diamond moderators get an automatic flag for this already.  If you spot it and you don't believe that a diamond mod has seen it yet, a custom flag with links to each question would do.

Comment: @Makoto, I see. Thanks for the clarification and the advice!

Comment: As a better example, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334764/5358284) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722936/5358284), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2967654/5358284), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033208/5358284), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6311089/5358284) and a handful of others. They are exactly the same o_0

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ, yep, but they are not made by the same person with copy/paste within a couple of minutes.

Comment: [Meta.SE on this subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)

Comment: @Machavity, thank you! I've seen that, cause ChrisF shared the link in the comments to his answer.

Comment: I've actually voted for dupes like that (particularly homework), usually they are closed as a dupe really quick and its not a problem. However, when it is a repeat OP or several OPs posting variants of the same assignment (many times both are happening) - I've found mention it in the language's chat can help. Also, it helps to stop people from answering. I would not use this as the official answer (use a mod flag for same person esp.) but it can be a quick way to make users (and mods who frequent a language tag) aware.

Comment: I've been called on this, and I still think it is better to have multiple identical/similar answers on multiple questions - deleting them makes no sense to me. Especially since the close duplicate system doesn't work in reality as it should in theory. Until we can get rid of broken duplicate questions I still believe there is far more value in having answers to the questions - even if the answers are copy/paste.

Comment: @JGreenwell -- "it helps to stop people from answering" ... is that really what we want on a Q&A site? People to stop answering questions?

Comment: I have seen instances where several people have encountered problems with very different symptoms but the same underlying cause, and in such cases closing as a duplicate seems unreasonable; pasting a copy of the answer seems entirely appropriate. I really resent it when SO gets paternalistic and requires me to make artificial and trivial differences to the answer in  such cases.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I'm talking about homework dumps which when answered are then handed in as original work by the OP? Yes, these should not be answered and either closed as dupe or just closed. It actually helps the OP to do so because then they don't have to fail their work when a TA or Professor finds their SO post (beyond they actually did their own work so as to learn). Now if it is a legitimate "I tried this but its not working" that happens to be related to homework I would make that the dupe target (and/or just close the others) and answer that legitimate question or evaluate as normal

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In this case the answers are subtly different, so the automatic duplicate answer detector won't flag them.

In this case the simplest thing is for you to flag one of the answers pointing out that it's essentially the same as the other(s). Make sure you point out why the system won't have flagged them. If there are differences in the actual answer (not just the preamble) then flagging is not appropriate as the answers are different.

Given that the "code" parts are identical and the only difference are in in the preamble, I'd say that these answers are essentially identical.

One of the answers has already been deleted and I've just deleted the second, leaving the oldest answer intact.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As you and @Carcigenicate have pointed out, it is already dealt with. But for me personally it is helpful anyway, in order to know what to do, if I stumble upon a similar situation in the future.

Comment: Why is it important to point out why the system wouldn't have flagged them?

Comment: @FrankerZ - so we know what we're looking for when handling the flag. We get 100's of flags a day, the more information we have with each flag, the easier it is to process and get the right resolution. In this case if you say the answer is identical but the auto-flagging hasn't happened we have to double check the answers. If you tell us that the code is the same (for example) we know what we're supposed to be looking for,

Comment: To know the internal workings of the automatic flagging system that pokes diamond mods is a bit much to ask of the average user, I would think.

Comment: @Lundin to that end I created a [FAQ on this very subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317987/what-flags-are-automatically-raised-by-the-system)

Comment: Why oh why oh why would we delete what can only be described as: **a perfectly correct, and extremely useful, answer**.  Is this for real?

Comment: @Fattie - this is why we don't like duplicate answers - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227 - but basically we don't want content split across several questions. We'd much rather have all the answers on one question and all duplicates pointing at that question.

Comment: I guess I often see the situation (particularly in software) where there are a number of fairly **different** questions - which have the same answer.  The link you gave just points out that if it is a duplicate question, sure close as dupe.  (That being said, close as dupe rarely works, it can sit for years, or "decades" now.  So even then a dupe answer seems great.  But again, I'm talking about when the questions are not dupes.)  Anyways, cheers

Comment: Chris, the linked faq simply states, over and over (and over), as a given, that SO "doesn't like linked questions".  I'm genuinely mystified **why** this would be.  Does it reduce your SEO with google?  Is it a negative in the "points gamification"?  Is it as a driver to reduce duplicate questions?   I just don't see it - anyways.

Comment: Why were the answers deleted if the questions are not duplicates of each other? You say the questions were subtly different, so they were tailored to each question specifically? This seems so wrong.

Comment: @Clint, no I said that the *answers* were subtly different - but not different enough. If the answerer updates the answer they can be undeleted.

Comment: @ChrisF Sorry, yes I meant answers. It still seems wrong though. Future readers will view these questions and a (possibly) correct answer will be missing because it's "a duplicate answer". IMO that's a huge fail on SO's part and directly conflicts with the goals of the site.

Comment: @Clint if the questions are duplicates then one should be closed to point to the other. If they're not duplicates then the answer should be edited at which point it could be undeleted.

Comment: @Fattie Relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267318/213575 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340344/792066