# Duplicate question comments filter/blacklist also prevents us from flagging duplicate answers for moderator attention

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, deleted-answers, comment-flags

This unhelpful error message is for duplicate questions, not answers. It's completely out of context and doesn't make any sense at all.

[image: "Don’t flag mistaken duplicate suggestions; instead, edit the question: make the title specific and detailed, then explain why the answers to the other question do not solve this problem."]

Here is a link to the answer that needs moderator attention:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32437538/148844

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684807/spring-boot-jpa-configuring-auto-reconnect/32437524#32437524 .. the user posted the exact same answer before and he shouldn't ... it has nothing to do with the answer of user5101998

Comment: OK but that's to a different question. I've posted the same answer to different questions before.

Comment: Hmmmm that's a funny result of the duplicate message. If I recall correctly, users were flagging "Possible duplicate of..." comments as unwelcoming, and a Mod got fed up with those flags and requested a regex to block flags saying "Duplicate"

Comment: As for posting the same answer to multiple questions, see [What (if any) action should be taken when the same answer appears on several questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372460/7795130) and, from MSE's FAQ: [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/363946)

Comment: I found the post I was thinking of, it was Yvette who brought it up, and Shog who implemented it: [Shog's answer to: When is a comment hostile or unfriendly? (Educating newer users how to flag comments)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373929/7795130)

Comment: Why on earth is this being downvoted? The error message describes a duplicate question. The post Chloe is trying to flag is an answer (an answer allegedly from a duplicate question, sure, but not a "mistaken duplicate suggestion"). Chloe is reporting this as a bug, and rightly so. How can anyone not see the obvious non-sequitur in the error message?

Comment: @BoltClock http://idownvotedbecau.se/nofreehandcircles/ (jk)

Comment: @BoltClock: Probably because the flag would actually have been wrong (even though, as it would not have been *trivially* wrong, it should undoubtedly have been let through and decided by a mod properly, rather than auto-blocked like the goofiness we see from askers.)

Comment: These error messages are complete nuisance. Just the other day I was unable to comment on a nuance of using the value of `-1` in code, because `-1` triggers the "Do not explain your downvotes" error.

Comment: @GSerg The limitation is removed now.

Comment: @Chloe can you confirm that this is now fixed on main?

Comment: It still gives the error "Don't flag mistaken duplicate suggestions; instead, edit the question: make the title specific and detailed, then explain why the answers to the other question do not solve this problem." @SamuelLiew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about that. The purpose of this check is to discourage folks from flagging their questions for reopening; moderators generally are not inclined to reopen questions unless there's clear evidence supporting it, and if that's provided in the form of an edit then moderators don't even need to be involved.

But you're quite right, this is not terribly applicable to answers. Henceforth, the check will only fire now if "duplicate" isn't being followed by "answer".

Regex is: `\bnot\s+(a\s+)?duplicate\b(?!answer)`

Comment: Why not test the object to see if it is a question or answer instead? Using regular expressions are very flaky. What if someone said "This answer is not a duplicate."? What if they started the sentence with a capital "Not"? https://regexr.com/4689c

Comment: Because currently I don't have the ability to differentiate between flags on questions and flags on answers, @Chloe. That might be worth adding at some point, but this is a fairly niche case; less than two dozen false-positives in the entire history of Stack Overflow. FWIW, the regex is run case-insensitive.

Comment: Just ran into this issue [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379940/flag-dialog-will-not-submit-if-the-message-box-contains-duplicate?noredirect=1#comment668563_379940). While probably not a frequent occurrence, it would be nice for the popup to be informational, and not stop every attempt to flag the question