# Flag dialog will not submit if the message box contains "not a duplicate"

Tags: support, flags

I've currently tried to submit the following flag:

> @user is abusing his gold badge in order to close questions he feels should be closed, but aren't even duplicates. The linked question is not a duplicate, and he admitted it in the comment section.

But I'm presented will the following red box:

[image]

Just because the word duplicate exists in a message box, doesn't mean the flag should be summarily dismissed. This is indeed an issue that only a moderator can handle, and I think if it shows this popup, it should not prevent further submits (This should act just as a reminder, and then if they hit submit again, or perhaps an "I acknowledge" button, it should submit normally)

Comment: Actually, I think it's matching specifically "not a duplicate". The idea is to prevent people from using it to request a moderator reopen their duplicate question. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378875/6083675). If that's the regex they use, it's pretty easy to beat, as regexes tend to be for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Laurel I ended up using an `ē` to get around the filters, but seemed kinda hackish to me, in order to submit the flag.

Comment: Can we get a link to the question?

Comment: @csmckelvey This post is referring to an issue that was caused by flagging a particular question, and I'd rather not bring attention to a user who should be dealt with by the mods.

Comment: Well, I wanted to confirm the claims you have made here but I guess we will just take your word for it.

Comment: I think that I saw the question and if so it appeared to be of very low quality

Comment: VLQ is not a reason to close as a duplicate (Although, if it's a duplicate of others, than sure, I agree)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, but it certainly should have been closed for other reasons or for appropriate duplicate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(From the comments)

> This post is referring to an issue that was caused by flagging a particular question, and I'd rather not bring attention to a user who should be dealt with by the mods.

Well... It has *something* to do with the question, since I put this block in specifically to discourage folks from flagging duplicates for reopening when they hadn't edited the question.

Which you haven't. Nor has anyone else.

Also, this isn't currently an issue, since after you talked to the person who closed it they saw your point, tried to find a better duplicate, and then gave up and just reopened the question. So... There's actually nothing for a moderator to do now anyway...

...Except close the question. So I dug up some better duplicate links and closed it again. Next time, maybe just suggest a better duplicate link to the person who closed it & cut out the middle man?

Comment: It was their comment back that caused me to raise the flag. Something along the lines, "I know, but it needed to be closed".

Comment: It... Kinda did... They're asking a classic "other side of an airtight hatchway" question, which strongly suggests there's a heck of a lot of relevant stuff they're not telling us. But I certainly agree that the first two duplicate links weren't useful. Sometimes just spending a few seconds more searching makes all the difference. Anyway, you did good - communication FTW!